# How do i debug the cause of a system crash if i know exactly when the crash is going to occur?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, windows-11, crash, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS TUF A17(2022) laptop  running windows 11 pro with everything up to date. I have a weird windows crash issue where bluetooth stops working first and if i click on any settings or menus related to Bluetooth the system completely freezes(no BSOD screen 95% of the time) immediately and crashes after a 10-20 minutes. If my bluetooth mouse gets disconnected from the laptop while using it, it's only a matter of time before the crash happens. Now that i know when it's going to crash, is there a way for me to setup some sort of driver monitoring software that can keep an eye on the system and record what exactly caused the error? I know it looks like a bluetooth driver or hardware issue but since this happens so randomly without any pattern i'm unable to figure out what(driver or hardware) that needs to be fixed. ASUS support is abysmally incompetent as they keep reinstalling with windows home edition(which the laptop came with) and see if that fixes the issue. Their hardware issue detection software was also unable to find anything. Though reinstalling windows never actually fixed the issue it is however delays the time before this crashing occurs again, which is causing them close the case. I've tried having only windows drivers, only OEM drivers and both but Nothing worked.

Event viewer shows critical error with following info:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" /> 
  <EventID>41</EventID> 
  <Version>9</Version> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <Task>63</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-05-12T19:03:08.9995743Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>27122</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-P2LTLUT</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="Checkpoint">16</Data> 
  <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">4</Data> 
  <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">9</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceIdV2">9</Data> 
  <Data Name="LongPowerButtonPressDetected">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="LidReliability">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="InputSuppressionState">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonSuppressionState">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="LidState">1</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I know it sounds like a simple bluetooth driver issue but i want to be sure it's not a symptom of another issue. Whether it is Microsoft or ASUS that responsible for fixing this. Any help to pinpont the root cause of the crash is appreciated.

Comment: [whocrashed](https://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) was my go to when my systems were less reliable, its worth a shot here.

Comment: Without a .dmp file, it will be next to impossible to diagnose this issue since you will be unable to run WinDBG and summit the analysis of the .dmp file which will indicate the true reason for the crash,

Comment: @Ramhound I do have the DUMP file but it's a small dump file. I don't have the complete dump enabled as i though it's harder to share that with anyone anyway. I can post the small dump file in here if it's possible.

Comment: I am not going to run your file through WInDBG. That would be on you to [edit] your question to contain enough information to answer your question.  We don't need the file. 
We need the output of the WinDBG analysis.